# Prevent a regex with capturing groups from acting on matches of a string that re preceded by a specific word and at the same time succeeded by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "((PL_ADVB)alrededor ((NOUN)(del auto rojizo, dentro de algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego dentro del baúl rápidamente abajo de una caja por sobre ello vimos una caña." #example input

place_reference = r"(?i:[\w,;.]\s*)+?"
list_all_adverbs_of_place = ["adentro", "dentro", "al rededor", "alrededor", "abajo", "hacía", "hacia", "por sobre", "sobre"]
list_limiting_elements = list_all_adverbs_of_place + ["vimos", "hemos visto", "encontramos", "hemos encontrado", "rápidamente", "rapidamente", "intensamente", "durante", "luego", "ahora", ".", ":", ";", ",", "(", ")", "[", "]", "¿", "?", "¡", "!", "&", "="]

pattern = re.compile(rf"(?:(?<=\s)|^)({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_all_adverbs_of_place)})?(\s+{place_reference})\s*((?={'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in list_limiting_elements)}))", flags = re.IGNORECASE)

input_text = re.sub(pattern,
                    lambda m: f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]}{m[2]}){m[3]}" if m[2] else f"((PL_ADVB){m[1]} NO_DATA){m[3]}",
                    input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #--> output
```

How to make the regex in the variable called as `pattern` only capture if and only if the text to capture is not in the middle of `((NOUN)` **"the captured text"** `)`

This way you should prevent this string

`((NOUN)(del auto rojizo, dentro de algo grande y completamente veloz))`

become in this other string...

`((NOUN)(del auto rojizo, ((PL_ADVB)dentro de algo grande y completamente veloz)))`

And this because `dentro de algo grande y completamente veloz` is in the middle oF `((NOUN)` and `)`. It is very important that for the regex to decide not to capture the blocking area in the string, it is in the middle of these 2 limiters.

The correct output would be:

```
'((PL_ADVB)alrededor ((NOUN)(del auto rojizo, dentro de algo grande y completamente veloz)). Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro del baúl) rápidamente ((PL_ADVB)abajo de una caja) ((PL_ADVB)por sobre ello) vimos una caña.'
```

As can be seen in the rest of the areas of the string where the **blocking pattern** (in this case is `((NOUN)` **blocking area** `)` ) was not present, the replacements were made.

Comment: Regular expressions are generally very poor at determining if a match is "inside" something.

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to place a simple negative lookahead `(?!s\b)`, or try to be more specific by establishing some concrete boundaries `\b(\(\(NOUN\))?` and  `\b(\))?`, but the problem I was having is that I can't be sure where the match will be located within those boundaries, so I was having a hard time with that. Perhaps there is nothing better than this for this particular case.